# Provided an invalid file

Tags: git, ssh-keys, assembla

I created a git repository on assembla, and i tried to clone it, but i got a message:

"Permission denied (publickey, keyboard-interactive) 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
Please make sure  that you have the correct access rights and the repository exists"

I searched for an answer and I figured out that it has to do something with the ssh keys. I followed this steps: http://pokit.org/get/img/1e6295f88c7abb8df09308d3dc8af3ca.jpg but when I want to upload the key to my assembla profile it says: "You provided an invalid file. Please, check if it's a SSH public key file and then try one more time."

I've been using assembla for a couple of months and I didn't have problems like this. I used existing repositories though. The problem occured when I created a new repository.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are providing your public key and that is in the proper format, sometimes some key generators confuse the format, it should be something like this:

ssh-rsa  AAAAB ... LOTS of other chars== comment@something.usually

You can just copy and paste it into the box in your profile instead of uploading the file.

Remember - it must be only your public file, either an RSA or DSA key is fine.  Your private file stays private.  So if both public and private are in same file, this will not work.

Comment: Thanks man, you guided me to the right path, I used puttygenerator instead and now assembla saved the key. But i still can't clone, do I need to do something locally?

Comment: I bet your git is not finding the ssh key you generated - you might want to give this tutorial a try that has both tortoisegit and git-bash instructions: http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/77264/Setting-Up-Git-on-Windows-in-Four-Easy-Steps

Comment: Tortoise git did the thing and it's much more simple then the console. Thank you Michael! :)